# Using alias in LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql

I have a table where I store friendship relations.

It has the columns id, userA and userB (the id of userA is always smaller than the id of userB).

I try to SELECT all friendship relations of a specific user:

```
SELECT CASE friendships.userA WHEN (?) THEN friendships.userB ELSE friendships.userA END AS friend_id, users.username FROM friendships
LEFT JOIN users ON friend_id=users.id WHERE userA = (?) OR userB = (?) ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT ? OFFSET ?;

$stmt->bind_param("iiiii",  $user_id, user_id, $user_id, $requestsPerLoad_db, $offset);
```

I get the following error message:

> Unknown column 'friend_id' in 'on clause'

What is wrong with this statement? I can get the value of $row['friend_id'] but cannot use it in the left join?

Comment: friend_id is an alias, you can't use it in join condition. You'll have to use the complete expression or your can evaluate the expression in subquery and then use it

Comment: The complete expression is dependent on the `CASE`. So should I just use $row['friend_id'] in a new query and SELECT FROM my users table to get the username of the friend? Edit: Or maybe I should simply try to use `CASE` again in the same query.

Answer (score 1):

This is your query:

```
SELECT (CASE f.userA WHEN (?) THEN f.userB ELSE f.userA END) AS friend_id,
       u.username
FROM friendships f LEFT JOIN
     users u
     ON friend_id = u.id
WHERE f.userA = (?) OR f.userB = (?)
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
LIMIT ? OFFSET ?;
```

`friend_id` is defined in the `SELECT`, so it cannot be used elsewhere in the same query.  You would have to use a subquery.  One simple solution is to move the logic to the `ON` clause.  Here is one method:

```
ON (u.id = f.userA and f.userB = ?) or
   (u.id = f.userB and f.userA = ?)
```

Another method is to skip the `LEFT JOIN` altogether and move the logic to the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT u.id, u.username
FROM users u
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
              FROM friendships f
              WHERE f.userB = ? AND f.userA = u.id
             ) OR
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM friendships f
              WHERE f.userA = ? AND f.userB = u.id
             ) 
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
LIMIT ? OFFSET ?;
```

The advantage of this approach is that the query might be able to take advantage of appropriate indexes.

Comment: I do not understand how the last solution is not very slow. As far as I understand the query, every single row of the users database is checked by taking the u.id of the current row and using this value in the WHERE EXISTS condition until all rows from users are checked. I have a feeling that I missunderstood the flow of this query, if yes could you please explain how it works and which indexes would be suitable.

Comment: @JuliusS. . . . In either case, the `users` table will need to be scanned.  The advantage of the second approach is that it can use indexes on `(UserA, UserB)` and `(UserB, UserA)` to resolve the query.

Comment: Ok, I will use some `EXPLAIN` to compare these statements and try to understand. One thing left: Your query tries to `ORDER BY timestamp` but I get an error, telling me that timestamp is not a column of the users table. That's right, I actually want to order by the timestamp column of the friendships table. Is there any way to modify your query?

Comment: @JuliusS. . . . Then `order by` something else.  Your query does not specify where `timestamp` comes from.

Answer (score 0):

That's because it's a derived column (or an alias) and not a part of friendships `table`. You can't join two tables on a column which doesn't exist in either of those.

An alternative way to get all the friends is with `UNION` query as shown below (I am not sure why `join` is needed as the column is present in `friendships` table only):

```
SELECT userB
FROM friendships
WHERE userA = ?

UNION

SELECT userA
FROM friendships
WHERE userB = ?
```

Answer (score 0):

I added the CASE statement in the ON statement and it works:

```
SELECT CASE friendships.userA WHEN (?) THEN friendships.userB ELSE friendships.userA END AS friend_id, users.username FROM friendships
LEFT JOIN users ON CASE friendships.userA WHEN (?) THEN friendships.userB ELSE friendships.userA END =users.id WHERE userA = (?) OR userB = (?) ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT ? OFFSET ?;

$stmt->bind_param("iiiiii", $user_id, $user_id, $user_id, $user_id, $requestsPerLoad_db, $offset);
```